# node.js on google app engine: different version running vs specified in package.json

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a node application on GAE (Google App Engine) flex environment. In the code, package.json specifies: "node": "8.11.4":

```
{
  "name": "prismic-universal-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "public/js/compiled/server.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.11.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
...
```

But when I open a Cloud Shell window from the google cloud console the project and run 'node --version', I get v8.9.4

Reading through google's documentation, I don't see anything yet about using a different version from what's in package.json. Does anyone know if google has another way to determine what version of node will ultimately be used? Or is there another spot where Node.js version can be set that may be conflicting with package.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/) is a GCP product separate from GAE (flexible). It does **not** execute on your GAE flexible app instance. From [Virtual machine instance](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/features#virtual_machine_instance):

> When you start Cloud Shell, it provisions a [g1-small Google Compute
>   Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types) virtual machine running a Debian-based Linux operating
>   system.

The info you obtained is from that VM.

To check the info on your GAE flexible app instance, you need to connect to it specifically, see [Connecting to the instance](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/debugging-an-instance#connecting_to_the_instance).

Comment: Yes now I can see that my project does use the correct node version, I was just looking in the wrong place- thank you!